# Delete registry keys with subkeys using winreg on python

Tags: python, key, registry, winreg

i am currently making a function that uses `winreg` to help me delete all the subkeys of a registry key. my current code

```py
import winreg as wr

def delsub(k0, k1, k2=""):
    if k2 == "": current = k1
    else: current =  f'{k1}\\{k2}'

    openkey = wr.OpenKey(k0, current, 0, wr.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
    infokey = wr.QueryInfoKey(openkey)
    for x in range(infokey[0]):
        subkey = wr.EnumKey(openkey, 0)

        try: wr.DeleteKey(openkey, subkey)
        except: delsub(k0, current, subkey)

    wr.DeleteKey(openkey,"")
    openkey.Close()
```

then i basically went to a random directory thing on regedit and created a key with 2 subkeys inside on the path `Computer\HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\test`. then i ran the function

```py
delsub(wr.HKEY_USERS,r'.DEFAULT\Control Panel\test')
```

it gave me an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 18, in <module>
    delsub(wr.HKEY_USERS,r'.DEFAULT\Control Panel\test')
  File "main.py", line 7, in delsub
    openkey = wr.OpenKey(k0, current, 0, wr.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
```

i tried giving it administrator access and same thing, so i really dont understand why

i get an error when opening the key though. the error doesn't explain much and i need some help
also im knew to winreg so if i did something extremely stupid here please let me know

Comment: Works fine on my system as long as I run vscode as Adminsitrator. Also works when I run python via Powershell in admin mode. I just copied your code and everything works as intended.

Comment: Trying it again today on both powershell and cmd it actually works. Maybe I forgotten to give it administrator access yesterday.

Comment: I always run MS DOS as an Administrator. This has not prevent me from getting a fat "Access denied" when I tried to delete en empty (with no values) key using 'wr.DeleteKey(key, subkey)'.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why but it works now when i run it on administrator mode. Maybe yesterday I forgotten to give it admin access.